# How to make next hover animation start only after previous hover animation ended?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to hide one element and display another on hover. But I have problem that when I have many elements like this and hover on them one after another the hover animation works on all of them at the same time, but I need to start new hover animation only when previous animation ended, how I can make this? Thanks!

My code:

```
 $('.fractional-titles-wrapper').hover(function () {
    $(this).closest(this).find('.fractional-short-title').hide('slow')
    $(this).closest(this).find('.fractional-full-title').show('slow')
  }, function () {
    $(this).closest(this).find('.fractional-full-title').delay(1000).hide('slow')
    $(this).closest(this).find('.fractional-short-title').delay(1050).show('slow')
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

[setTimeout](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-settimeout-function-examples/) seems to be the ideal solution. triggering the next animation when the previous has ended. Just set the time to the length of the animation and you will be good to go.

```
var explode = function(){
alert("Boom!");
};
setTimeout(explode, 2000);
```

Hopes this helps.